# how to use a specific index of a array in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

want to take a specific data in reducer . I got an error which says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I'm calling the action at `useEffect` with a empty array dependency

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getOrderDetails(props.match.params.guid)
  }, [])
```

here's where I'm trying to use it

```
<div>
 {props.orderDetails[0].data}
  </div>
```

Comment: Well as the error says, `props.orderDetails[0]` is undefined. Which means the order details array is empty, probably because it is initially before the data is loaded into it. Also your ternary code has a syntax error, cos if `props.orderDetails` is an array as it seems to be, then `props.orderDetails.data` doesn't make sense, it will be undefined. Arrays don't have a `.data` property

Comment: yeah but the array that i'm getting from API has, i'm updating my question

Comment: Ok so you're fetching it from an API, which means it's initially empty, so `props.orderDetails[0]` is initially undefined. You have to check if there's any elements in the array before trying to render stuff in it, something like `{props.orderDetails.length ? <div>{props.orderDetails[0].data}</div>:null}

Comment: I think it is problem with the 'props.getOrderDetails'. codesandbox will help.

Comment: Looks like you still haven't quite got the correct null check in place. If I understand correctly, `props.orderDetails` is the array, so `prop.orderDetails.data` is flat-out incorrect. Check as @Jayce444 says, that the `props.orderDetails` array has *some* truthy `length` property ***before*** attempting to access into the array and any object properties, i.e. `props.orderDetails.length && props.orderDetails[0].data`, or if you can use Optional Chaining `props.orderDetails?.[0]?.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think what you are asking is why you can use it some places and not... Remember Redux is the simple source of truth. So. It is getting rendered first before for component mounts, so in the useEffect()  you can use setState, useState and make the 'props.orderDetails.data' a state variable.
that should fix the problem because it will execute AFTER the component mounts.